# XPAGES - Issues in Richtext field

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

Issues in Richtext field.

I have a form with 5 rich text field and binded these fields in a XPage with field upload control. when i upload same files in 2 rich text field, error message "item already exist" is shown. how to resolve this problem

Comment: Are they bound to different fields?

Answer (score 2):

Have you bound each file upload control to each field too (using the value property)?

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{document.field1}"></xp:fileUpload>
```

Comment: Maybe this bug affects file uploads too? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO67196
It has been fixed in 8.5.3 FP2.

Comment: We are having domino 8.5.3 fp2 .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using fileUpload renaming feature?

```
<xp:fileUpload... useUploadname="false" filename="fileName1.txt"></xp:fileUpload>
```

This way you could define if the issue is really in the equal filenames.